# To have R chunk in line with text using knitr

Tags: r, syntax-highlighting, knitr

How to have R code (R chunk) inline with my text?

Example:

***Please install the package by using install.packages("ISwR")***

whereby, install.packages("ISwR") is automatically highlighted as R chunk using knitr?
In other words, I would like to have R code at the same line with my text.

Answer (score 2):

Following [a suggestion from Yihui](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/knitr/DTTYdjwqrQ8),

```
\documentclass{article} 
<<setup, include=FALSE>>= 
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) { 
  if (is.numeric(x)) return(knitr:::format_sci(x, 'latex')) 
  knitr:::hi_latex(x) 
}) 
@ 
\begin{document} 

Please install the package by using \Sexpr{'install.packages("ISwR")'}. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This idea does generalize to R HTML documents (replace `hi_latex` with `hi_html`), but unfortunately this will not work for R Markdown. The solution can be obtained from CSS + `knitr:::hi_html()`, but I do not have time to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 3 backticks ``` if you want the encapsulated code **NOT** to be executed inline . E.g.

````
There were ```nrow(cars)``` cars studied
````