# Knitr inline chunk options (no evaluation) or just render highlighted code

Tags: r, syntax-highlighting, knitr

I cannot find information on whether it is possible to specify options for inline chunks in knitr. I've just tried specifying them, as in the regular chunk, but this gives an error.

What I need is to include R code with highlighting in a PDF, but without evaluating it. This can only happen with inline chunks due to the format of the context. Or perhaps there is another way to include highlighted code.

To provide an example, I need something in the lines of:

```
Some text about something with `r eval=FALSE 1+1` inside the sentence.
```

This particular syntax gives:

```
Error in parse(text = code, keep.source = FALSE) :
<text>:1:11: unexpected ','
1: eval=FALSE,
```

Comment: does `eval = FALSE, echo = TRUE` do what you want

Comment: @TylerRinker Unfortunately not. I have edited the question to be more clear about what I need.

Comment: [partial duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16185350/471093) (for the highlighting part)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [Yihui you can do](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/knitr/DTTYdjwqrQ8),

```
\documentclass{article} 
<<setup, include=FALSE>>= 
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) { 
  if (is.numeric(x)) return(knitr:::format_sci(x, 'latex')) 
  highr::hi_latex(x) 
}) 
@ 
\begin{document} 

the value of $\pi$ is \Sexpr{pi}, and the function to read a table is 
\Sexpr{'read.table()'}. 

<<test2>>= 
rnorm(10) 
@ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Could you imagine how this would look in Markdown? The setup chunk is not the issue, rather the contents of the function (latex & hi_latex portions)

Comment: Yihui [recently hinted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16185350/471093) that a little trick would be needed for markdown.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to live without highlighting then. I will leave the question open for now just in case.

Comment: It should be `highr::hi_latex`